# Asp.Net Identity: Reset Password

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, forgot-password, reset-password

I keep getting invalid tokens when I create a reset token and try and change a user's password.

I'm confused as to why the token is instantly invalid. When I run this method, the dummy user I create is found, a token is created, and when I hit the ResetPassword method, its result is "Invalid Token".

AccountController:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
{
    var userManager = UserManager;
    ApplicationUser user = userManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);

    if (user != null)
    {
        var code = await userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);

        var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { UserId = user.UserID, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

        //Test token immediately 
        var result = await userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.UserID, code, "randomPassword");

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage("no-reply@abc.com", user.Email);

        string baseUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority;
        string resetLink = string.Format("<a href='{0}'>Click Here</a>", callbackUrl); 

        // Email service - send email 
    }

    return RedirectToAction("EmailSent");
}
```

I even created a new project from scratch and tried the same thing. and everything worked as it should. So it has to be some setting I changed or something that is different, but I'm not seeing it.

**Application Setup:**
I changed Identity to use Ints as the user Ids rather than the stock guid string.

Is there any thing else that is required for this to all work correctly? Is there something that I'm missing that is causing the invalid tokens in my project?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://tech.trailmax.info/2015/05/asp-net-identity-invalid-token-for-password-reset-or-email-confirmation/ ? I suspect in your case `SecurityStamp` value on user record is empty.

Comment: Also, is this a debugging code you show? If you just need to change password, you can do it without tokens

Comment: Yep, the security stamp was empty. That was it! I am also trying to allow user's to reset their passwords via the email they signed up with, so changing the password without a token is not the direction I needed.

Comment: Good, glad it helped!